# Facebook Share: 302 Found

Tags: facebook, facebook-sharer

While sharing a video on Facebook, I am getting error 302 found. The url is working fine, but the preview section says 302 Found instead of the original video.
here is the link to the video:
http://www.teambeachbody.com/showcase/-/bcp/2071537921001

[image]

What can be the issue, and what do I need to check?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/

Comment: thanks, let me check that and share the findings

Comment: I guess, there are multiple redirections, and facebook is following only a couple of them. and trying to scrape from a url which is in middle of redirection. how to fix that?

Comment: It looks like your system doesn’t stop redirecting – presumably because it tries to set a cookie during the redirect, and then redirects back to the “real” URL and checks for the existence of the cookie there – and if it is not present, it starts the same thing again. The FB scraper doesn’t support cookies – so you will need to not do that redirect dance in the first place if the FB scraper is the one making the request (can be recognized by its User-Agent header.) And btw., users that do not accept cookies in their browser likely won’t be able to use your site as well.

Comment: @CBroe Please post that as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your system doesn’t stop redirecting – presumably because it tries to set a cookie during the redirect, and then redirects back to the “real” URL and checks for the existence of the cookie there – and if it is not present, it starts the same thing again. The FB scraper doesn’t support cookies – so you will need to not do that redirect dance in the first place if the FB scraper is the one making the request ([can be recognized by its User-Agent header](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/faqs#scraperinfo).)

And btw., users that do not accept cookies in their browser likely won’t be able to use your site as well.